# Did Stan Lee get erased by Thanos

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, stan-lee

In the *Avengers: Infinity War*, post Thanos' Finger Snap, do we have any information regarding the Stan Lee cameos?

Is he alive or erased due to the snap?

Comment: If next avengers movie takes too much time to come to theatre, if Stan died (in real life), it could be a tribute to him by making him disappeared due to Thanos incident. <= IMO . In universe, we don't kn ow yet. probably next movie provide some clarification or probably not

Comment: Hint: Read the comics.  While the MCU doesn't follow the comics to the letter, it follows a very similar arc.  And there's no way Avengers 4 isn't going to follow the arc of the Infinity Gauntlet.

Comment: Stan Lee isn't, as far as I know, playing one person in the MCU who happens to pop up all over the place. He's a completely different person in each movie, so even if the snap had erased every single person we've seen Stan Lee play to date, that wouldn't prevent him from doing more cameos going forward.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ... actually one of the credit scenes in GotG Vol 2 has Stan discussing his various cameos with a species called "The Watchers" , hinting that the cameos are all of the same person.

Comment: Seemingly not, it says that he's [still alive at 95.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee)

Comment: I think Stan Lee died in infinity war because that is a perfect way to end Stan Lee from the Marvel universe... even if he was always on the bus. *****Stop reading if you have not seen Captain Marvel***** He was healthy in Captain Marvel, but I doubt he is in Endgame!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
By the way R.I.P. Stan Lee.
Tony Stank... Dies
Stan Lee... Dead
Black Panther... Dead

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Stan Lee Lives

We don't know how the finger snap will be resolved so it's possible that the whole thing will be undone in *Avengers 4* but what we do know is that Stan Lee has **already** filmed that cameo.

> During his appearance at Wizard World Nashville 2017, Lee's personal manager revealed that the legend has already filmed his cameos for five upcoming MCU entries, up to and **including 2019's Avengers 4**.
>
> Noticeably missing from that list is *Captain Marvel*, which hits theaters in March 2019, prior to Avengers 4's release. It's unclear when Lee is planned to shoot a cameo for that, but one presumes it's on the MCU radar, as is a Lee cameo for 2019's sequel to *Spider-Man: Homecoming*. Despite his advanced age, there's no reason to assume that Lee will be gone anytime soon, so here's hoping he remains part of the MCU for many years to come.
>
> <sup>[**Screenrant**](https://screenrant.com/stan-lee-cameos-avengers-3-4-thor-black-panther/)</sup>

Comment: But what if he's cameo is inside the Soul stone. I wouldn't put his status in bold. Good find though

Comment: _"... a Lee cameo for 2019's sequel to __Spider-Man__: Homecoming"_ this actually proofs that being in an upcoming movie _does not_ mean that one has survived the Snappening.